# Using wget filtering only folders needed

Tags: wget

I'm trying to get some files in a specific website directory using `wget`:

```
wget -r http://www.example.com/Item/<folder>/<files>
```

Knowing that the page http://www.example.com/Item/ causes a 404 page, how can I get the files and folders inside it and neglect other folders and extra files such as the following:

- http://www.example.com/b/something/index.html
- http://www.example.com/Category/file.html
- http://www.example.com/Collection/demo.html
- http://www.example.com/Javascript/data.js
- http://www.example.com/Stylesheet/type.css
- etc.

Comment: If the web server is configured not to display a directory listing, there's no way to get one.

Comment: Thanks. good to know. I guess I'll just download everything in the site and get the files and folders I need.